# Writing greek text in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, greek

Is it possible to compile the following example using pdfLaTeX showing the correct font for greek text, and not the default CMR?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Εισαγωγή}

Αυτό είναι ελληνικό κείμενο.
\selectlanguage{english} this is latin text.
\selectlanguage{greek} και αυτό είναι ελληνικό κείμενο.

\[
a = b + \gamma
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but if the fonts haven't been setup up yet for pdflatex it would take some time and some skills.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer And technically speaking, they wouldn't be unicode fonts anymore, would they?

Comment: @Sverre: pdflatex can include otf and ttf-fonts (but not subset them).

Comment: i have updated the post with a minimal example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can pdfLaTeX really include otf? It can include ttf for sure but I didn't know it could use otf.

Comment: Check out http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/

Comment: @Sverre Yes but doesn't the process convert the fonts to type1? As far as I know lcdf tools work by creating type1 fonts from the opentype fonts, along with support files. pdfLaTeX then uses the type1 fonts rather than the original otfs.

Comment: @cfr: Try it out: Add to a hello-world document which loads cmr10.pfb the line `\pdfmapline{=cmr10 CMR10 <<lmroman10-regular.otf}`.

Comment: Solved with fonts from GFS (Greek Font Society), e.g. kerkis.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you try to replace lines: \usepackage{txfonts}, \usepackage{kerkis,kmath} with lines: \usepackage{tgheros}, \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
the compiled pdf shows the greek text with CMR font although the usage of package tgheros!!! Why's that?

Comment: Uh, no? The [kerkis](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/greek/kerkis/) package is not a Unicode font. Your question was how to use a _Unicode_ font with ``pdflatex``. If that in fact was not your question, you should have asked what you actually wanted to accomplish (which seems to be "how to write Greek with ``pdflatex``"). So please ask what you actually want to accomplish, otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: @Sverre Yes you're right! But I want to show the difference between kerkis (a pure greek font) and tgheros (a random font selected from tex font database). So, what can we do if we continue with tgheros font?

Comment: Both ``kerkis`` and ``tgheros`` are LaTeX fonts, not Unicode fonts. I don't understand what you're getting at now. Please edit your question and ask what you actually want to ask. Otherwise, as said, the question will be closed as it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Sverre Updated my question!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

TeX Gyre Heros does not support Greek. You can see this in the opentype version of the fonts:

```
otfinfo -s fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyreheros-regular.otf 
DFLT            Default
cyrl            Cyrillic
latn            Latin
latn.AZE        Latin/Azeri
latn.CRT        Latin/Crimean Tatar
latn.MOL        Latin/Moldavian
latn.NLD        Latin/Dutch
latn.PLK        Latin/Polish
latn.ROM        Latin/Romanian
latn.TRK        Latin/Turkish
```

Similarly, the LaTeX fonts include support for no suitable encoding.

The fonts do include Greek characters which may be used in, for example, typesetting mathematics. But there is no support for typesetting Greek text.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no reason to use `\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}`. Use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. The font `TeX-Gyre-Heros` is a sans-serif font, so it'll be used only if the text is set to be sans-serif.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\begin{document}

\section{Εισαγωγή}

Αυτό είναι ελληνικό κείμενο.
\selectlanguage{english}this is latin text.
\selectlanguage{greek}και αυτό είναι ελληνικό κείμενο.

\[a = b + \gamma\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "the correct font for greek text, and not the default CMR" means that the produced greek text is not in tgheros font! Can't you see it in your attached figure?

Comment: @TeXFun - Maybe should reconsider carefully your preference for using pdflatex instead of either xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the option `iso-8859-7` would seem to be out of place.

Comment: @Mico The focus of my question was on the font of greek text, and not how to use inputenc package.

Comment: Right. I don't know how the Greek font face in Computer Modern looks. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @TeXFun - Is your comment a response to my comment to @Sverre about not using `iso-8859-9`, or to my comment to you about maybe reconsidering the use of pdflatex? Please clarify.

Comment: @Sverre The Greek font face in CMR font looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/HUy7V.png. This is exactly the same font of your attached image that you posted above.

Answer (score 1):

tex-gyre-heros does not support Greek under pdfLaTeX.
Under Xe/LuaTeX, only the base letters are present, accented letters and other symbols are missing.

The simplest solution would be to switch to a sans-serif font that supports the Greek "LGR" font encoding like https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gfsneohellenic or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gofonts.

Another option is to set up a substitute just for Greek with
the `\DeclareFontfamilySubstitution` command
added to the LaTeX kernel in the 2020 release, see [ltnews31](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf).

The third option would be to use LuaTeX with a Helvetica variant that supports Greek or with language-specific fonts set up via Babel or Polyglossia.